# Redux syntax confusion when calling dispatch function in a child component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was working on this Redux tutorial, and I have some confusion about the syntax. Codes in parent component

```
const TodoList = ({todosa=[], onRemovePressed}) => (
    <div className="list-wrapper">
        <NewTodoForm />
        {todosa.map(todo => <TodoListItem todo={todo} onRemovePressed_child={onRemovePressed} />)}
    </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todosa:state.todos,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onRemovePressed: (index) => dispatch(removeTodo(index)),
```

And in the **NewTodoForm** child component I see something like this

```
const TodoListItem = ({todo,onRemovePressed_child}) => ({
        <div className="todo-item-container">
        <input>Write Something Here</input>
        <h3>{todo.index}</h3>
            <div className="buttons-container">
                <button className="completed-button">Mark As Completed</button>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {onRemovePressed_child(todo.index)}} //WTF is happening here????
                    className="remove-button">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
})
```

What is `{onRemovePressed_child(todo.index)}`?? What kind of syntax is this? It does not look like a function to me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question

> What is `{onRemovePressed_child(todo.index)}`?? What kind of syntax is
> this? It does not look like a function to me at all.

## Answer

It is the body of a function. The entire function is

```
() => {onRemovePressed_child(todo.index)}
```

but perhaps would be more recognizable as

```
() => {
  onRemovePressed_child(todo.index);
}
```

Typically single line functions don't need the body brackets though, and can be written as such

```
() => onRemovePressed_child(todo.index)
```

So when defined anonymously inline as a callback handler it is written as

```
onClick={() => onRemovePressed_child(todo.index)}
```

Comment: I can see that is an arrow function. My question is, what is, onRemovePressed_child(todo.index)? Doesn’t seem like a function to me

Comment: @LearnerSamuelX What about it doesn't seem like a function? It's an identifier, `onRemovePressed_child`, followed by parenthesis and an argument, `todo.index`. This is the syntax to invoking a function.

Comment: thank you for clarifying that. Now its all cleared up. I guess i will just have to get involved in writing or reviewing more codes because now I am more used to passing a variable as a props to a child component but not so with passing a function as a props.

Comment: @LearnerSamuelX Is part of the confusion over how to know when a passed prop is a function or not? There exists a fair amount of naming convention, i.e. if a variable is named `onPressHandler` or anything starting with the prefix "on", there's a very high chance it's a callback function. You can also define the component [propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html). Think of these as the API of the component, i.e. what can be passed to it; it is a sort of type checking so you'll also see warnings from react if the wrong type is passed as a prop, i.e. string vs number.